# Problem setting up Gitosis for Git

Tags: git, ssh, gitosis

Here is the Problem I am having

I followed the Steps mentioned in the Doc for setting up Gitosis
http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#gitosis

I completed the following steps successfully

Install gitosis
Initializing the gitosis account

Checkout the gitosis-admin repository to my local machine and add a Public Key of my Web Server to the keydir Directoty and add Configuration to allow the Web Server Account to write.

Commit these changes in gitosis-admin and push them. This adds the Public Key to authorised_keys file for the gitosis user.

Now I go to my Web Server and try to push a new repository

```
$ cd project-X
$ git remote add origin gitosis@gitosis-server:project-X.git
$ git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

Here it asks me to provide the Password, which it shouldn't and use the identity file instead.

Please Help.

Comment: Not really solving your problem, but gitosis is old and no longer supported. [Gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) replaces it.

Comment: What os is your webserver? Are you sure it's not asking for the passphrase for the key itself?  Is it just the web server client, or do other gitosis users/computers have the same issue?  Does the key pair work if you try and login to a different host that has that key installed?

Comment: It doesn't ask for password after I changed the configuration for ssh in my server to use the correct identity file. Also I had to change gitosis config for the User The User Name given in config need to be exactly the same as the public key file name except .pub.

Answer (score 0):

The user isn't "gitosis". It's "git", so `git remote add origin git@gitosis-server:project-X.git`. Also, use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) instead of gitosis. Gitosis is old and dead, and it's starting to smell funny.

Comment: The User I had created was gitosis not git. I got it to work somehow, the names of the public keys and the name of the user in the config needs to exactly match. you cant include the server name in config and leave it in the name of the public key and vice versa. Also I am now using gitolite as also suggested by @Ikke here and by people in git IRC Channel.